# How to perform a custom search using a button formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I would like to create a button to search my mail's Inbox view for emails which contain a unique string found in the subject field of the selected document. For this, I have created the following button formula. This correctly retrieves the unique string but the search itself does not work.

```
SearchStringLeftPart := @Left( Subject; "] [");
SearchString := @RightBack( SearchStringLeftPart; "[");

@SetViewInfo([SetViewFilter];SearchString;Subject;0;0)
```

Please can someone advise if @SetViewInfo can be used for this purpose & if so what is wrong with the formula. Otherwise how else can I achieve the task using a button formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't accomplish that with @SetViewInfo.

But, in combination with a short agent you can show only those documents in view which have current document's unique Subject substring in their Subject field.

Create a **formula agent** "SelectSubjectSearch" with

- target "All documents in view"
- option "Selects documents in view"
- formula

  `SELECT @Contains(@LowerCase(Subject); @LowerCase(@Environment("SubjectSearch")))`

[image]

Create a **formula button** which

- writes the search string into environment variable "SubjectSearch"
- selects the option "View / Show / Selected Only" in menu
- calls the agent "SelectSubjectSearch"

Button code:

```
SearchStringLeftPart := @Left( Subject; "] [");
SearchString := @RightBack( SearchStringLeftPart; "[");

@SetEnvironment("SubjectSearch"; SearchString);
@Command([ViewShowOnlySelected]);
@Command([ViewShowOnlyUnread]);
@Command([ViewShowOnlyUnread]);
@Command([ViewShowOnlySelected]);
@Command([RunAgent]; "SelectSubjectSearch")
```

The tricky part is the "View / Show / *Selected Only*" selection. As `[ViewShowOnlySelected]` just toggles between "*Select Only*" and *not* "*Select Only*" and you don't know which status currently is set we have to call a double `[ViewShowOnlyUnread]` which resets `[ViewShowOnlySelected]` to *not* "*Select Only*". The first `[ViewShowOnlySelected]` sets the information bar to "You are seeing: the item you selected" and the second `[ViewShowOnlySelected]` does set for sure "*Select Only*".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately our IT admin does not allow to run agents. So I am not able to test this.

Comment: That's sad. You really get an error if you choose menu "Create / Agent" in your database?

Comment: Yes, I get "You do not have sufficient privilege to save Lotus Script or Java agents."

Comment: Does that include not being able to create Formula or Simple Actions agent? Both agent types would work for this case.

Comment: I had another go at this, Lotus saved the agent even though it says I don't have the privileges. I have now managed to get this working using exactly the above pieces of code. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is the subject exposed in the first (sorted) column of the view? 
IIRC, SetViewInfo only filter the view on the first column, which alse must be sorted.

Update: Did not refresh the page after I got back from lunch, so did not see that there already was a correct answer.

Comment: The only answer I see is yours, Karl-Henry.

Comment: Strange, I thought I saw someone else responding... I promise, I did not drink anything at lunch! :-)

Comment: they must be using some of those fancy noSQL Databases, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Create a search view with first column sorted by subject and use view.getAllDocumentsByKey(...)to get the documenta you search